# The volume of a cube is decreasing at the rate 10m^3/hr. How fast is the total surface area decreasing when the surface area is 54m^2?

Tags: calculus

These types of problems are confusing me like crazy. My teacher's work is below. I understand how she got everything from Given and Known, but after that she lost me. Can anybody explain this please? Thank you
[image: Teacher's work]

Comment: Yes, I see that she did used those. I see how she got V=squareroot(SA/6)^3. But why did she take the derivative after that? And where did the 1/6 *dSA/dt come from?

Comment: Ah right. I think I understand it now. It is just complicated

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate way to solve the problem:

Since $V=s^3$, $\frac{dV}{dt}=3s^2\frac{ds}{dt}$;$\;\;\;$ so $s=3\implies -10=3(9)\frac{ds}{dt}\implies \frac{ds}{dt}=-\frac{10}{27}$.

Then $A=6s^2\implies\frac{dA}{dt}=12s\frac{ds}{dt}=12(3)(-\frac{10}{27})=-\frac{40}{3} m^{2}/\text{hr}$

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnXhs.jpg)

I think this might be more clear to understand

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).